# Can't download apps from App Store since updating to iOS 9.3.2

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, iphone

I updated to iOS 9.3.2 and now I can't download anything on the App Store. It is always stuck on "loading". I also tried restarting and logging out my Apple ID and it doesn't help at all. I have a stable connection and my brother has an Android device and he can download smoothly so I'm sure that it's not a connection problem and I think the problem here is the new OS update.

Comment: Try restarting your phone and if that doesn't work, download a free app.

Comment: Sometimes I have to power off, then turn the phone back on. Not sure if there's a difference between restart and power off, turn on.

Comment: Switch your language to Spanish and then switch it back to English. Always works for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Restore from an iCloud/iTunes backup](http://m.wikihow.com/Restore-an-iPhone)

Make sure your iTunes is up to date on your computer beforehand. The update itself hasn't caused a problem on my iPhone 5s so it may be something to do with your phone.